# URL forwarding in deploying tomcat web application

Tags: java, tomcat7, web-deployment

I have tried to look if this question was asked before but I couldn't find an answer.
I want to deploy tomcat web application, let's call it X. Now when I type URL on the browser, say www.example.com/X, the project is deployed successfully.

But I don't want a user to go through all of that. What I want to achieve is that a user has only to type www.example.com then he will be automatically directed to www.example.com/X. Can I configure this in the server? or what is the convenient way to go with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved with the `Server.Service.Engine.Host.Context` element in conf/server.xml

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

`<Context docBase="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\webapps\X"
                   path="" reloadable="true" />`

Add the configuration, then restart the tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you! that was successful.